# Read column of CSV file as array

Tags: csv, j, apl

I am trying to read a column from a CSV file into an array.

So far I have successfully read the file with the code below.

```
load 'csv'

data =: readcsv '/Users/max/Desktop/prices.csv'
```

Typing `data` in the interpreter  brings the following table (which in what I expect)

```
┌────────────┬────────┬────────┐
│Date        │Price   │Open    │
├────────────┼────────┼────────┤
│Jun 01, 2022│29,798.5│31,793.1│
├────────────┼────────┼────────┤
│Jun 02, 2022│30,455.5│29,798.6│
├────────────┼────────┼────────┤
│Jun 03, 2022│29,700.9│30,455.7│
├────────────┼────────┼────────┤
│Jun 04, 2022│29,864.3│29,700.9│
├────────────┼────────┼────────┤
│Jun 05, 2022│29,913.0│29,865.1│
├────────────┼────────┼────────┤
│Jun 06, 2022│31,367.6│29,911.2│
├────────────┼────────┼────────┤
│Jun 07, 2022│31,128.8│31,370.3│
├────────────┼────────┼────────┤
│Jun 08, 2022│30,201.6│31,127.2│
├────────────┼────────┼────────┤
```

Now my question is, how do I extract a column like 'Open' and then transform it
into a variable like `"31,793.1" "29,798.6" "30,455.7" "29,700.9"`

Comment: Are you also expecting an APL answer? (Asking because of your [tag:apl] tag)

Comment: An apl answer would be great. Is there a CSV library for APL?

Comment: I've added how to parse the numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the data as you would use any other boxed array.

```
data
┌────┬────┬────┐
│col1│col2│col3│
├────┼────┼────┤
│a   │b   │c   │
├────┼────┼────┤
│d   │e   │f   │
├────┼────┼────┤
│g   │h   │i   │
└────┴────┴────┘

NB. Column 3
2{"1 data
┌────┬─┬─┬─┐
│col3│c│f│i│
└────┴─┴─┴─┘

NB. Column 3 without the header
}. 2{"1 data
┌─┬─┬─┐
│c│f│i│
└─┴─┴─┘

NB. Col3 data unboxed and joined
,> }. 2{"1 data
cfi
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am new to J how do you convert a boxed array
into a normal array like `c f i` instead or `cfi` ?

Comment: @M4X_ there are a lot of ways to do that, depending on what your data are and what you want to do with them. Generally, if you want a c-like array of strings you would keep them boxed.

Comment: where can I learn more about boxed arrays? I would like to apply some verbs like +/ to them

Comment: @M4X_ usually, in J, you don't extract the data and then compute the operation on it. Instead, you modify a function that operates on data to be able to operate on data that has the shape you want. For instance, you could use the adverb `each` to operate "inside" each box, instead of actually unboxing elements.

Answer (score 2):

In Dyalog APL:

```
      data ← ⎕CSV '/Users/max/Desktop/prices.csv'
```

Right-reduce to get the rightmost column, then drop the header:

```
      1 ↓ ⊢/data
┌────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┐
│31,793.1│29,798.6│30,455.7│29,700.9│29,865.1│29,911.2│31,370.3│31,127.2│
└────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┘
```

OR, indicate a single header row, then get the main data with `⊃` etc.:

```
      ⊢/⊃⎕CSV '/Users/max/Desktop/prices.csv' ⍬ ⍬ 1
┌────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┐
│31,793.1│29,798.6│30,455.7│29,700.9│29,865.1│29,911.2│31,370.3│31,127.2│
└────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┘
```

---

By the way, `⎕CSV` can even parse the numbers for you so you get a list of numbers instead of a list of strings. The `4` here means "attempt to parse cells as numbers":

```
      ⊢/⊃⎕CSV⍠'Thousands' ','⊢'/Users/max/Desktop/prices.csv' ⍬ 4 1
31793.1 29798.6 30455.7 29700.9 29865.1 29911.2 31370.3 31127.2
```